# How to retrieve the value while displaying contents in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, session, struts2, ognl

I am facing problem in below code

```
<s:form action="updateBankInfo.action" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"      theme="simple">
  <s:actionerror />
  <div style="font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:30px; padding-left: 250px;">Bank Info</div>


  <div>
    <div class="label"><s:text name="Payee Name*   :"/></div>
    <div class="input"><s:textfield  value="%{#session.payeeName}" name="bean.payeeName" readonly="false" /></div>
    <div><s:fielderror fieldName="bean.payeeName"/></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="label"><s:text name="Bank*   :"/></div>
    <div class="input"><s:textfield value="%{#session.bankName}" name="bean.bankName" readonly="false" /></div>
    <div><s:fielderror fieldName="bean.bankName"/></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="label"><s:text name="Branch*   :"/></div>
    <div class="input"><s:textfield  value="%{#session.bankBranch}" name="bean.bankBranch" readonly="false" /></div>
    <div><s:fielderror fieldName="bean.bankBranch"/></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="label"><s:text name="City*   :"/></div>
    <div class="input"><s:textfield  value="%{#session.city}" name="bean.city" readonly="false" /></div>
    <div><s:fielderror fieldName="bean.city"/></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="label"><s:text name="A/C No*:"/></div>
    <div class="input"><s:textfield  value="%{#session.accountNo}" name="bean.accountNo" readonly="false" /></div>
    <div><s:fielderror fieldName="bean.accountNo"/></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="label"><s:text name="IFSC Code   :"/></div>
    <div class="input"><s:textfield  value="%{#session.IFSCCode}" name="bean.IFSECode" readonly="false" /></div>
    <div><s:fielderror fieldName="bean.IFSECode"/></div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" style="width:107px;height:34px;margin-top:100px;margin-left:10px;font-size:1.67em;background-color:#d9d9d9;clear: left;" onclick="form.submit()"><s:text name="Update"/></button>
</s:form>
```

In this all the values I am fetching from database and storing in sessions. For the first time `bankName` will not be containing any values, and I have used validator method to do validation, so if I give value for `bankname` and click on submit. I am not able to retain the `bankName` value since I have given `value="%{#session.bankName}"`, since `bankName` does not contain any value. How to retrieve the value?

Comment: The title of this post is not descriptive enough. Can you post your action class code, that way it will be easier to understand your issues and help you.

Answer (score 1):

Create the `bean` instance and getter/setter, i.e.

```
private Bean bean = new Bean();
public Bean getBean() { return bean; }
public void setBean(Bean bean){ this.bean = bean; }
```

To retain the values you should

```
Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
session.put("bankName", bean.getBankName());
// the same put for the others.
```

See the use of session in the [simple example](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/SimpleLogin+with+Session).

Comment: @ roman I have done that in action class see I have bank_details table in which I have value for payeeName and City ...rest others I need to update using this form....and in the same form I can edit also So I have used that session variable to get the data from the database 2nd time

Comment: You have fields mapped by name to action class `bean.bankName`, so OGNL will call `getBean().setBankName(String ...` the same for the other fields.