# Cannot load parameters in Struts 2 action

Tags: java, jsp, parameters, struts2, ognl

In reference to [Struts 2 and business objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036504/struts-2-and-business-objects) and the code stated there:

- I `cannot load the rp.randomCode` as it gives it `null`. I have `getters/setters in both RequestParam class and the SendMessageOrStartChatAction`. I can load (get the request `param` value if I use the old code though)
- I cannot use `private fields` in the `RequestParam class` because if I want to do `rp.randomCode`, the random code field in the RequestParam class should be `public`. (dont want to use `rp.getRandomCode()` though).  Now, this is not good as fields *should* be private.

**new code:**

```
public class RequestParam{
    private int userId;
    private int groupType;
    private int groupId;
    private String groupTitle;
    private String groupMemberIds;
    private int randomCode;
    private String message;
    private int messageId; //internal class ues
    //public getters and setters here

}

public class SendMessageOrStartChatAction extends BaseActoinSupport{

    private RequestParam rp;
    //public getters and setters here

    @Override
    protected void doExecute() throws IOException {

        //check if it had random code in db, (msg already saved in db)
        if(ChatDao.randomCodeExists(rp.randomCode)){
           // ...........
        }

    }

}
```

---

**old code:**

```
public class SendMessageOrStartChatAction extends BaseActoinSupport{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int userId;
    private int groupType;
    private int groupId;
    private String groupTitle;
    private String groupMemberIds;
    private int randomCode;
    private String message;
    private int messageId; //internal class ues

    @Override
    protected void doExecute() throws IOException {

        //check if it had random code in db, (msg already saved in db)
        if(ChatDao.randomCodeExists(randomCode)){
            messageId = ChatDao.getMessageIdThatMatchesRandomCode(randomCode);  
            write(messageId);

        }else{
            if(groupId <= 0){
            //create group 
                groupId = ChatDao.createChatGroup(userId, groupTitle, groupType);
                String[] memberIdsArray = groupMemberIds.split("=="); 
                ChatDao.addUsersToGroup(groupId, memberIdsArray);
            }
            //save message
            messageId = ChatDao.saveMessage(userId,groupId , message);
            // queued: may be put this in last viewed messages here. may be.
            write(messageId);       
        }

    }

}
```

How to load parameters using the code above?

Comment: `put on hold as unclear what you're asking by Dave Newton, Kevin Panko, Mihai Maruseac, mdml, Sean Vieira 10 hours ago.`   ya, unclear, thats why I got a valid answer and an upvote to my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose in the JSP you have a form tag and one or more input fields. Each field has a `name` attribute. This attribute is magic for Struts2 maps form fields to action attributes using OGNL syntax. Nested beans like `rp` should be mapped with prefix `rp.`, so OGNL will get the reference of that bean before setting properties named after dot. To make it working make sure the `params` interceptor is referenced in the action configuration, because it's responsible for populating bean instance properties of your action instance.

Comment: so I will get the `name` form field value by `rp.name` if the `RequestParam class (rp field var)` has a `name` field with getters and setters for it? if yes. I tried and it didnt worked.

Comment: Did you read what I have written? Post the JSP, you didn't post it in the first nor in the second questions.

Comment: Would the word "instance" tell you something?

Comment: there is no jsp. its `url.com?userId=2342&randomCode=34534` ... give a real world example please. I can load (get the get request param value if i use the old code though). why not with RequestParam rp; in the new code

Comment: try `url.com?rp.userId=2342&rp.randomCode=34534 ...` but before see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18098135/573032

Comment: Thats my point. struts 2 should **auto pick up** the `randomCode` if just `System.out.println(rp.randomCode)` provided that rp was the filed var in that class and `rp` inturn had a filed called `randomCode`.

Comment: No, struts2 is not treating `rp.randomCode` like java code it's treating it like OGNL expression. The actual java code is executed getRp().setRandomCode(34534)`.

Comment: ok. I will try. Thanks. if you do have some actual precise code. That would be asset for other stack viewers. Lastly, what about my second point about public fields visibility?

Comment: it's a bad choice and not like object-oriented.

Comment: hm.. but any way. centralizing the params in a `rp` is recommended in struts 2 I guess?

Comment: centralizing is not a good term for it, aggregating or modelling is better fit.